# Redshift performance tuning on a JOIN query

Tags: join, amazon-redshift

I'm having trouble with performance on the following query:

> SELECT [COLUMNS] FROM TABLE A JOIN TABLE B ON [KEYS]

If I remove the join, leaving only the select the query takes seconds. With the join, it takes **30 minutes**.

Table sizes are A (844,082,912) & B (1,540,379,815) rows.
Distribution and sort keys are equivalent to the join KEYS.

Looking on AWS graphs, I see (attached) one node with has some 100% CPU utilisation for a short time. [image]

Looking on system table (svv_diskusage) I am not sure what I see (attached), as it does not indicate (as far as I can tell)  if one node has much more data than the others.[image]

if the issue is faulty distribution, how can I see it?
is it something else?

Answer (score 1):

Here https://aws.amazon.com/articles/8341516668711341 (Uneven Distribution) you can see an example of the same graph style: one node is working harder than the others, which indicates your data is not evenly distributed.

Regarding svv_diskusage, it describes the values stored in each slice. If the slices are not relatively evenly used, that's an indicator for a bad distribution key. Try the following query to get a higher abstraction over distribution amooung nodes and not slices:

```
select owner, host, diskno, used, capacity,
(used-tossed)/capacity::numeric *100 as pctused 
from stv_partitions order by owner;
set search_path to '$user', 'public', 'ic';
select * from pg_table_def where tablename = '{TableNameHere}';
```

Comment: I think this post (disclaimer - I wrote it) might be interesting if you want more information about this topic: http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/miziel/2015/08/12/how-we-squeeze-the-juice-out-of-redshift/